# Why does + + treat a string as a number

Tags: javascript

If you execute the following statement

```
"Test a b " + "c"
// Output
// "Test a b c"
```

but if you execute the following it treats `"c"` as a number.

```
"Test a b " + + "c"
// Output
// "Test a b NaN"
```

Why does two consecutive `+` signs treat the string as a number?

*Tested in chrome `40.0.2214.111 m`*

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 8):

When you do `"Test a b " + + "c"`, it is doing `("Test a b ") + (+ "c")`, the first `+` is the string concatenation operator and the second `+` is the [**unary `+` operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)), which converts to a *Number*

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've learnt something new, I can use the unary + operator to cast to a number.